Custom block registered within custom category in WordPress is not showing in admin end
I am developing a custom theme in which I am trying to include some custom blocks by registering a custom block category. But it is not showing in the admin end.
Though when I execute the command it executes properly without any error.
npm run dev

I might be missing something which I am still not getting. Below is the code:
Package dependencies:
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.25.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.25.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.24.7",
    "@svgr/cli": "^8.1.0",
    "@wordpress/base-styles": "^5.4.0",
    "@wordpress/block-editor": "^13.4.0",
    "@wordpress/blocks": "^13.4.0",
    "@wordpress/components": "^28.4.0",
    "@wordpress/compose": "^7.4.0",
    "@wordpress/data": "^10.4.0",
    "@wordpress/dependency-extraction-webpack-plugin": "^6.4.0",
    "@wordpress/element": "^6.4.0",
    "@wordpress/eslint-plugin": "^20.1.0",
    "@wordpress/hooks": "^4.4.0",
    "@wordpress/i18n": "^5.4.0",
    "@wordpress/icons": "^10.4.0",
    "@wordpress/scripts": "^27.9.0",
    "@wordpress/server-side-render": "^5.4.0",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^7.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.9.0",
    "sass-loader": "^16.0.0",
    "sass-mq": "^5.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack": "^5.93.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@wordpress/babel-preset-default": "^8.5.0",
    "sass": "^1.77.8"
  }

Build Paths for JS and CSS:
if( ! defined( 'NINTYNINE_BUILD_JS_URI' ) ){
   define( 'NINTYNINE_BUILD_JS_URI', untrailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . '/assets/build/js' );
}

if( ! defined( 'NINTYNINE_BUILD_CSS_URI' ) ){
   define( 'NINTYNINE_BUILD_CSS_URI', untrailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . '/assets/build/css' );
}

if( ! defined( 'NINTYNINE_BUILD_CSS_DIR_PATH' ) ){
   define( 'NINTYNINE_BUILD_CSS_DIR_PATH', untrailingslashit( get_template_directory() ) . '/assets/build/css' );
}


assets.php file inside build folder:
<?php return [
    "js/main.js" => [
        "dependencies" => ["wp-polyfill"],
        "version" => "4d1ec442c34233d2338a",
    ],
    "js/single.js" => [
        "dependencies" => ["wp-polyfill"],
        "version" => "cf309fb462d151e0903f",
    ],
    "js/editor.js" => [
        "dependencies" => ["wp-polyfill"],
        "version" => "20e59da245b068507d19",
    ],
    "js/blocks.js" => [
        "dependencies" => [
            "lodash",
            "react",
            "wp-block-editor",
            "wp-blocks",
            "wp-components",
            "wp-i18n",
            "wp-polyfill",
        ],
        "version" => "e700597aa4ab30101b1c",
    ],
];


There is class-assets.php file:
<?php
/**
 * Enqueue theme assets
 * 
 * @package NintyNine
 */

namespace NINTYNINE_THEME\Inc;

use NINTYNINE_THEME\Inc\Traits\Singleton;

class Assets {
    use Singleton;

    protected function __construct(){
        //load class.
        $this->setup_hooks();
    }

    protected function setup_hooks(){
        /**
         * Actions
         */
        add_action( 'enqueue_block_assets', [$this, 'enqueue_editor_assets' ] );
    }

    public function enqueue_editor_assets() {
        
        $asset_config_file = sprintf( '%s/assets.php', NINTYNINE_BUILD_PATH );

        if ( ! file_exists( $asset_config_file ) ) {
            return;
        }

        $asset_config = require_once $asset_config_file;

        if ( empty( $asset_config['js/blocks.js'] ) ) {
            return;
        }

        $editor_asset    = $asset_config['js/blocks.js'];
        $js_dependencies = ( ! empty( $editor_asset['dependencies'] ) ) ? $editor_asset['dependencies'] : [];
        $version         = ( ! empty( $editor_asset['version'] ) ) ? $editor_asset['version'] : filemtime( $asset_config_file );

        // Theme Gutenberg blocks JS.
        if ( is_admin() ) {
            wp_enqueue_script(
                'nintynine-blocks-js',
                NINTYNINE_BUILD_JS_URI . '/blocks.js',
                $js_dependencies,
                $version,
                true
            );
        }

        // Theme Gutenberg blocks CSS.
        $css_dependencies = [
            'wp-block-library-theme',
            'wp-block-library',
        ];

        wp_enqueue_style(
            'nintynine-blocks-css',
            NINTYNINE_BUILD_CSS_URI . '/blocks.css',
            $css_dependencies,
            filemtime( NINTYNINE_BUILD_CSS_DIR_PATH . '/blocks.css' ),
            'all'
        );

    }

}

Finally, the class-blocks.php file
<?php
/**
 * Theme Blocks
 * 
 * @package NintyNine
 */

namespace NINTYNINE_THEME\Inc;

use NINTYNINE_THEME\Inc\Traits\Singleton;

class Blocks {
    use Singleton;

    protected function __construct(){
        //load class.
        $this->setup_hooks();
    }

    protected function setup_hooks(){
        /**
         * Actions
         */
        add_action( 'block_categories_all', [ $this, 'add_block_categories' ] );
    }

    public function add_block_categories( $categories ) {
        $categories_slugs = wp_list_pluck( $categories, 'slug' );

        return in_array( 'nintynine', $categories_slugs, true ) ? $categories : 
        array_merge( 
            $categories, 
            [
                [
                    'slug' => 'nintynine', 
                    'title' => __( 'NintyNine Blocks', 'nintynine' ), 
                    'icon' => 'table-row-after' 
                ]
            ]
        );

    }
   
}


After doing lots and lots of research. Those were some deprecated method that I used. Now the latest approach I have tried and it is working fine.
In class-assets.php
instead of using:
add_action( 'enqueue_block_assets', [$this, 'enqueue_editor_assets' ] );
use:
add_action( 'init', [$this, 'enqueue_editor_assets' ] );
And in class-blocks.php
instead of using
add_action( 'block_categories_all', [ $this, 'add_block_categories' ] );
use:
add_filter( 'block_categories_all', [ $this, 'add_block_categories' ] );
